# Graduate Program in Philosophy

Tags: german-philosophy, graduate-school

I have bachelor's and master's in pure Mathematics and currently I am a math phd student in the United States.

I was wondering can I get admitted to a European university (in Germany, Austria, Switzerland, etc) for a graduate program in philosophy?

Comment: Needs more info: what field do you wish to work in, what is your general background in philosophy?

Comment: @emesupap more like philosophy of mind. I didn't read philosophy systematically, but I'm familiar with Kant, Hegel, Marx, etc. Also, based on my math background, I'm familiar with logic, too

Comment: what is familiar? in any case, presumably you have writing samples, you should get them checked out by a professor to see if you have a chance. logic is good, but unless youre specifically interested in phil math/logic you probably won't need anything beyond a first course in model or proof theory

Comment: @emesupap i appreciate your help. Can you name some books or resources that any undergrad students must have read?

Comment: you should consult some undergrad syllabi. since you are already enrolled, you should attempt to see if you can take a course for letters of rec or feedback on writing samples, both of which will be essential.